# Changing string dictionary values into integers and adding them up

Tags: python, python-2.7

Kind of a strange question. Say I have the following dictionary:

```
dict = {'1':'123','2':'1234','3':'12345'}
```

I want to take each value, split it up into individual characters, change those characters into integers, and then add them up. The resulting dictionary would be this:

```
dict = {'1':'6','2':'10','3':'15'}
```

All help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
for k, v in my_dict.items():
    my_dict[k] = str(sum(int(c) for c in v))
```

I might add, I agree, this is a strange question.  It seems like there might be a better way to do what you need.

Comment: There is a better way... I just don't feel like rewriting a whole bunch of code ;/

Comment: Could use `my_dict.iteritems()` as you're not modifying size/keys

Answer (score 4):

A functional approach:

```
dict = {key: str(sum(map(int, value))) for key, value in dict.items()}
```